# How to do auto reload in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make this possible? I want to auto refresh my page after the history.go. I post my whole html

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/andris9/jStorage/master/jstorage.js"></script>

    <script>
        $.jStorage.set("reload", true);

        if ($.jStorage.get("reload") === true) {
            $.jStorage.set("reload", false);
            window.location.reload()
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function goBack(){
            window.history.go(-2);
        }
     </script>



    <title>Edit Success</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="content">

        <div class="md-modal md-show" id="modal-1">
            <div id="notifMessage">
                <h1>The information have been updated.</h1>
                <p><a onclick='goBack();'>View Patients</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

I edited it with my whole html and replaced what u post but still not working or maybe i'm wrong in implementing it

Answer (score 0):

You cant reload after you have gone back like this, because the code that comes after the user navigates away , will never be executed.

Instead, you need to store a variable either on server side, or on user browser, that tells the page to reload. And then...you write a script that reloads if such parameter exists.

e.g By using jStorage plugin you could do something like this

```
//add jstorage script to your pages, just copy paste this
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/andris9/jStorage/master/jstorage.js"></script>
```

then before you go back in history, you set the reload variable to true

```
$.jStorage.set("reload", true);
//Go back in history
```

and after user has gone back in history, you check if the reload parameter exists, and if so, do a reload.
code below would have to be loaded on every page, so you would put it into the header of your template, after jstorage scripts

```
if ($.jStorage.get("reload") === true) {
    $.jStorage.set("reload", false);
    window.location.reload()
}
```

Comment: Its not impossible, it just takes a bit more work :)

Comment: how can I implement this?

Comment: i tried it but its not working, what's the whole code for it?

Comment: thats pretty much it, nothing complicated.
you can get more info heare
http://www.jstorage.info/

you could also post a link to the site you are using it on.

Comment: Place "$.jStorage.set("reload", true);" into your goBack function, otherwise you set and delete that value instantly.

Comment: the code works fine.
you can see a working solution here:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/rainerpl/XuZ9J/8/show/light/?var=535

click goForward to go few pages ahead, then go back.

code can be seen here :
http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/XuZ9J/8/